# How to add constraint on integer range in mysql/MariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table with one column being BIGINT that I want to add a constraint on a certain RANGE of values.
For example, I want to allow 0 to 2M, but prevent 2M+1 to 3M, allowing 3M+1, etc. The database is MariaDB.

Looking to prevent two databases from overlapping values in shared resource pool.

Comment: Could you just use a `check` constraint with a bunch or `or`s and `and`s? Like https://dbfiddle.uk/pQHV3kXb ? I think this works as a constraint, although maybe there's not enough information to know whether this is a good idea or not.

Comment: `check` constrants are a good answer. Note `id between 3000001 and 4000000` is a valid expression. Use the mathematical power of `MOD` to perform that etc function like [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oJcGgrE0). @roger-dunn its much more useful if all ranges have the same number of entries, 2M in first and 1M in second seems odd. Workable, it just ends up as a more complex expression. Test boundary conditions. @EmdCoff, feel free to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with a `check` constraint. For example,

```
create table test(id bigint, 
 constraint blah check (
  id < 2000000 
  OR (id >3000000 AND id <4000000) 
  OR (id >5000000 AND id <6000000)
 ))
```

You can see it working in [this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pQHV3kXb). (This is just an example, since the pattern you want is not exactly clear to me.)

As danblack pointed out in the comments, you can likely write this more efficiently using `between` and/or `mod`. (`mod` will be really useful if there's a predicable pattern for what is allowed.)

```
create table test(id bigint, 
 constraint blah check (
  id < 2000000 
  OR (id BETWEEN 3000001 AND 4000000) 
  OR (id BETWEEN 5000001 AND 6000000)
 ))
```

As Akina pointed out in the comments, the `check` constraint requires MySQL v.8.0.16 / MariaDB v.10.2.1 (or higher).

The question implies you are adding this to an existing `bigint` column, but as Bill Karwin pointed out in the comments, you can use `bigint unsigned` as the type to avoid having to exclude/handle negative numbers in the `check` constraint.

Comment: It would be a good idea to make it `bigint unsigned` to prevent negative numbers.

Comment: It is safe to add a remark that CHECK constraint needs in MySQL v.8.0.16 / MariaDB v.10.2.1 (or higher).